# How to force this field to submit data?

Tags: django

I have a form that looks like [image: this]

I am trying to add a product. The description of which will be entered through this form. But my textarea dont send data to product

`html:`

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="form-label">Текст новости</label>
        <div id="blog-editor-wrapper">
            <div id="blog-editor-container">
                <div class="editor">
                    <textarea name="text" class="form-control" id="text" rows="3" required>TEXT</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`vievs:`

```
def create(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        obj, created = Posts.objects.get_or_create(title=request.POST.get("title"))
        obj.text=request.POST.get("text")
        obj.preview=request.POST.get("preview")
        obj.date=request.POST.get("date")
        obj.image=request.POST.get("image")

        obj.save()
```

`models:`

```
text = models.TextField('Текст статьи')
```

`Мy other fields (not custom) look like this`

```
<label class="form-label" for="blog-edit-title">Заголовок</label>
<input type="text" id="blog-edit-title" class="form-control" value="" name="title" />
```

Comment: What package do you use for the custom textarea? I am not sure if there is no need for execution of custom javascript logic, that will fill hidden/abstract input in the HTML with correct value, like `.refresh()`. Maybe also you won't binded it correctly...

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański i use vuexy for it